# stop crypttab asking for password for swap

Tags: luks

I instaled a fresh 11.04 system when it was released and set up full disk encryption with LUKS.  At first it asked me for a password for my three encrypted partitions:

```
/
/home
swap
```

Typing in the passphrase three times got frustrating, so I tried to set up /home and swap to decrypt from a keyfile stored on /.  I created the keyfile and enabled it on the two partitions.  My crypttab now looks like this:

```
root-root_crypt UUID=13c21bf6-4d92-42a7-877a-87cc31b1aa19 none luks
home-home_crypt UUID=ba90ce5b-9df7-4764-8a72-011bbb164db4 /root/keyfile luks
home-home_crypt UUID=ba90ce5b-9df7-4764-8a72-011bbb164db4 none luks
sda3_crypt UUID=e4677895-2114-4054-9f23-d36f6bb0e6a2 /root/keyfile luks,swap
```

This works fine for /home, which gets mounted automatically without asking for a password.  But cryptsetup still asks for a password for the swap space.  I've even tried adding noauto to the swap space so it wouldn't be set up at all -- once the system is booted I can enable it without the passphrase, so I thought I'd just add a late init script to do it, but even with noauto cryptsetup still asks for the passphrase.

Thanks!

Comment: For this reason, it's recommended to use LVM + LUKS in case of multiple partitions. Crypsetup can be used above or below the LVM layer (above -> filesystem, below -> disk). Using cryptsetup below LVM has the advantage that you need only one encrypted partition (the LVM one).

Answer (score 10):

Had the same question,  here is how i did it on ubuntu 12.04.1 and 12.10,

### --before starting make sure you have a backup and can also boot your system with ubuntu cd or usb; as if you make a mistake, your system may not boot anymore or you may loss data. i assume you have an encrypted ubuntu system with LUKS, inside LUKS you have 3 partitions, SYSTEM-BOOT (not encrypted), SYSTEM-SWAP (encrypted) and SYSTEM-OS (encrypted)--

u need to adjust UUIDs, SYSTEM-SWAP_crypt, SYSTEM-OS_crypt, SYSTEM-SWAP, SYSTEM-OS to the variation used on your system, pls see reference link below my solution for more info

**Get UUIDs:**

```
blkid
```

**Prepare >**

```
swapoff /dev/mapper/SYSTEM-SWAP_crypt
cryptsetup luksClose SYSTEM-SWAP_crypt
```

**Tell cryptsetup to compute the passphrase of the swap partition from the decryption key of the volume holding the root filesystem >**

```
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived SYSTEM-OS_crypt | cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/mapper/SYSTEM-SWAP --key-file -
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived SYSTEM-OS_crypt | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/SYSTEM-SWAP SYSTEM-SWAP_crypt --key-file -
mkswap /dev/mapper/SYSTEM-SWAP_crypt
```

**tell the system about swap partition, edit crypttab>**

```
nano /etc/crypttab
```

**=?  make sure two lines match**

```
SYSTEM-OS_crypt UUID=uuid-of-luks-containing-osroot none luks
SYSTEM-SWAP_crypt UUID=uuid-of-luks-containing-swap SYSTEM-OS_crypt luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived
```

**tell the system about swap partition, edit fstab>**

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

**=?  make sure u have this line**

```
/dev/mapper/SYSTEM-SWAP_crypt swap swap sw 0 0
```

**tell the system about swap partition, edit resume>**

```
nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

**=?  make sure u have this line**

```
RESUME=UUID=uuid-of-encrypted-swap-SYSTEM-SWAP_crypt
```

**update initramfs on boot partition >**

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

---

## Reference

The answer inspired by [Setting up an encrypted Debian system](https://web.archive.org/web/20170628211144/http://madduck.net/docs/cryptdisk/) (archived link):

> If you are using an encrypted Debian system, you likely have some
>   security requirements to meet. If that's the case, you must also use
>   an encrypted swap partition.
>
> The swap partition can be encrypted in two ways:
>
> - it can be recreated on every boot, using a random passphrase, or
> - it can be created like the other encrypted volumes with a persistent passphrase
>
> If you want to use suspend-to-disk, you cannot use the first approach
>   as it would overwrite your memory footprint stored in the swap
>   partition. Furthermore, you cannot use a key file like the other
>   partitions, since the root filesystem is not (and must not) be mounted
>   by the time the resume process starts and needs to read the decrypted
>   swap partition.
>
> The way I solved this is by telling cryptsetup to compute the
>   passphrase of the swap partition from the decryption key of the volume
>   holding the root filesystem; the cryptsetup package implements this
>   with `/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived`. Thus, to set up the swap
>   partition, I do the following, assuming `hda2` is the partition holding
>   the encrypted swap and the root filesystem is in `hda5_crypt`:

```
swapoff /dev/mapper/hda2_crypt
cryptsetup luksClose hda2_crypt
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/hda2
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived hda5_crypt \
  | cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/hda2 --key-file -
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived hda5_crypt \
  | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/hda2 hda2_crypt --key-file -
mkswap /dev/mapper/hda2_crypt
```

> To tell the system about this swap partition, we need to add it to
>   `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/fstab`; make sure, those files contain lines
>   like the following:

```
/etc/crypttab:
  hda2_crypt /dev/hda2 hda5_crypt luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived

/etc/fstab:
  /dev/mapper/hda2_crypt swap swap sw 0 0
```

> With this in place, as soon as you configure the system for
>   suspend-to-disk, the swap partition will be automatically set up
>   alongside the root filesystem very early during the boot sequence. To
>   figure out which swap partition to make available at that point,
>   cryptsetup checks the following:
>   asfasfafs
>   - a line like `RESUME=/dev/mapper/hda2_crypt` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`
>   - a resume device setting in `/etc/uswsusp.conf` (see `uswsusp.conf(5)`)
>   - an entry in `/etc/suspend.conf`
>   - a `resume=/dev/mapper/hda2_crypt` in the kernel command line
>
> You can inspect `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptroot` if you want
>   to know more about this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Would have +1'd if not simply copy/pasted without taking care of the formatting (which I just did). I like the "it can be recreated on every boot, using a random passphrase" approach here.

Comment: added the commands i actually used to the answer, i am going to test it on 12.10 too, will update the answer later

Comment: Okay. I assumed you copy/pasted it completely. Please change it to have clear on what changes you made to it to make it work. Would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: do not try it on 12.10 as I ran into a bug that prevents boot, I get "cryptsetup lvm is not available", Google search return bug reports. need to look into it more deeply but have no time, will let u know later.

Comment: updated the answer, my 12.10 system is now fully functional and asks for only one password,i did not **update-initramfs -u -k all** at the end that created the problem i mentioned on previous comment. @gertcdijk formated everything, hope u r happy now

Answer (score 5):

This probably indicates that the swap partition is being accessed during the `initramfs` portion of the boot process.  At this point the root file system has not yet been mounted, so any configuration files stored there won't be visible.

While the swap space is mounted after the root file system, there is a reason for the `initramfs` initialisation process to access the swap space: when you hibernate your computer, the contents of memory and system state is written to swap.  In order to resume from hibernation, it is necessary to check if the swap space contains a hibernation image which would require the pass phrase.

If you don't mind losing the ability to resume from hibernation, you can disable this behaviour by editing `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and commenting out the line starting with `RESUME=`.  After making the change, run `update-initramfs -u` to update the `initramfs` image.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I'm not sure I want to sacrifice hibernation.  I don't use it often, but when the battery wears down with out my noticing, it comes in handy.  Do you know if there's a way to have cryptsetup reuse the same password for /?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that.  And before you ask, don't try putting a copy of your keyfile into the `initramfs`.  While it would get rid of the passphrase prompt, it would also make it available to anyone with physical access to the disk.