# Encrypted home partition + encrypted swap + working hibernate

Tags: 13.10, encryption, hibernate, swap, trim

I would like to set up disk encryption on Ubuntu 13.10 such that I have

- plain `/`
- encrypted `/home` partition
- encrypted swap partition
- working hibernation and resume

As these requirements suggest, this is to protect me from a potential laptop thief reading my personal data. With `/` being unencrypted, it does not protect from somebody taking the laptop, installing a keylogger, and giving it back to me.

I have read [EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap) but it's written for Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm not confident that it still works or that it's the recommended way.

What would be up-to-date setup?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to set up an encrypted home and encrypted swap with working hibernate.

I use `uswsusp` and largely followed [this article](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/encrypted-swap-partition-on/) - still works for Ubuntu 13.10.

- On boot, I get two password prompts (one for home and one for swap) under the Ubuntu logo.
- With `apt-get install uswsusp`, Ubuntu automatically switched `pm-hibernate` to use uswsusp, so all GUI tools use it as well.
- On resume from hibernate, I get one password prompt as expected.

---

Some parts of my setup:

**Creating the encrypted partitions**

```
# For /home
sudo cryptsetup --cipher aes-xts-plain --key-size 256 --hash sha512 --use-random --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/sdb2
# For swap
sudo cryptsetup --cipher aes-xts-plain --key-size 256 --hash sha512 --use-random --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/sdb3
```

- I use `aes-xts-plain` because it is the fastest in `cryptsetup benchmark` (only works with cryptsetup >= 1.6). Many guides uses `aes-cbc-essiv`, but from what I've read so far, `xts` protects against watermarking just as well as `cbc-essiv`.  If you use partitions >= 2TB, you should use `aes-xts-plain64` instead of `-plain`. More info about these options and choices can be found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40218).
- After creating these partitions, you of course have to create the according filesystems on them, e.g. with `mkswap /dev/mapper/cryptoposwap`  and `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/cryptohome`.

**/etc/crypttab**

```
cryptohome   /dev/disk/by-uuid/8cef7fd1-cceb-4a4a-9902-cb9a5805643c   none   luks,discard
cryptoswap   /dev/disk/by-uuid/a99c196d-55df-460f-a162-00c4ea6d46e6   none   luks,discard
```

**/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=a4a2187d-a2d2-4a4c-9746-be511c151296  /       ext4   errors=remount-ro  0  1
/dev/mapper/cryptoswap                     none    swap   sw,discard         0  0
/dev/mapper/cryptohome                     /home   ext4   discard            0  2
```

- I use the `discard` option in boths `crypttab` and `fstab` to enable TRIM for the SSD I'm using.
- I had to adjust `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` away from the old swap UUID to the new `/dev/mapper/cryptoswap` to get rid of a warning at `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

---

This is still very similar to [EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap), but it looks like I didn't have to edit `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot`, `/etc/acpi/hibernate.sh` (if you have a hint why it was needed, please leave a comment - maybe the difference is that this setup uses `uswsusp`?).

Comment: +1 as your answer led me on the right track but i either mixed something up or it was because there is no `mkswap` performed after `luksFormat` which made me lack a UUID for cryptoswap (=the luksOpened swap-partiton). after further research i finally succeeded in getting hibernate working with the help of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/235992/44653) given to a related question.

Comment: @antiplex Yes, the filesystems must have been created with `mkswap` on `/dev/mapper/cryptoposwap`  and with `mkfs.ext4` (or other file system) on /dev/mapper/cryptohome` - I did not list these steps explicitly. Will update the answer accordingly.