# ubuntu 16.04; Screen won't return from sleep mode after desktop goes to sleep. also, would like to add hibernate mode to my pc

Tags: 16.04, suspend, hibernate, mode

Just as the title says, my screen won't return from sleep mode after my PC goes to sleep and I wake it up.
also, i would like to add hibernate mode to my pc. how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Hi there. What is the output of the command `ls -A /home`?

Comment: .ecryptfs  giovanni

Comment: Looks like you opted to encrypt your home partition during installation. This means ecryptfs is used to encrypt both your home and swap partitions by default. You may not realize your swap was encrypted because you aren't explicitly told this will happen when you choose to encrypt your home.

Comment: Your question has already been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462775/swap-not-working-on-clean-14-04-install-using-encrypted-home/541514#541514). There are a lot of different options, none of which are perfect...I can summarize them, but I highly suggest you read all the answers to the question I linked to so you understand the caveats of each workaround.

Comment: In short, here are your options. 1) on certain machines (see first answer to linked question for more info), you can more or less keep things how they are and just change some configuration files. You would **back up** and then change `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/fstab` to identify your swap by `/dev/sdXX` instead of by UUID and supply a randomly generated key when needed (`/dev/urandom`) 2) use an unencrypted swap partition (there are some risks involved, see the second answer to the linked question)

Comment: 3) Reinstall with full disk encryption 4) It may be possible to use `uswsusp`, although there is not much out there about successfully using this with 16.04...possibly see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396136/encrypted-home-partition-encrypted-swap-working-hibernate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap not working on clean 14.04 install using encrypted home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462775/swap-not-working-on-clean-14-04-install-using-encrypted-home)